# Vim command to paste over highlighted word

Tags: vim

I've only recently learned about use `v` command to mark a section I want to copy or cut. This is great!

But I'd like to use the `v` command to make the section I want to replace.

For example:

```
$another_obj->method_in_obj
$self->method_actually_in_obj
```

I want to mark "another_obj" and overwrite "self" with "another_obj". Basically I want to tell vim that, I want to take these 4 characters (self) and turn them into these 11 characters (another_obj) and have vim adjust my line accordingly.

So the final should be:

```
$another_obj->method_in_obj
$another_obj->method_actually_in_obj
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- cursor on `[a]nother`, pressing `yw`
- then `j` cursor is on `[s]elf`, press:`vawp`

Comment: nice. I'll accept this as correct when the wait time passes. For a +1, what's the `vawp` mean/do?

Comment: @Ramy it select the `self` and replace it with `another_obj`. you can press those keys slowly, you will see.

Comment: lol. yes I see that it worked. but what does the "a" do in vawp? v is mark, w is word, p is paste. but the a??

Comment: It's actually "v" for visual mode, "aw" for "a word", and then "p" for paste. The "aw" is one thing, called a "text object". Read `:help text-objects` and prepare to have your life changed.

Answer (score 1):

@Kent has outlined the basic approach: You `y`ank the source word, then `p`aste over the selected replacement. The downside is that you can do that only once, because that action overrides the original yanked text! To avoid that, you need to specify the black-hole register.

I do this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.